# Remapping files in the subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I want to have subdomains for my assets without cookies. For example, all CSS, JS and images will come from `http://static1.website.com/`, but this `static1` can change its name to any number, like `static2`, `static3`, `static4` and so on... All subdomains must have same files (like file `http://static1.website.com/test.js` will be available on all subdomains). You ask why? Because website loads faster, when it loads assets from different domains (for example 5 of them will come from `static1`, another 5 from `static2` and so on...). Structure of my subdomains looks like this:

```
_subs
  /assets
  /static1
  /static2
  /static3
```

All files are stored at `_subs/assets` but should be accessible anywhere. So I decided to use htaccess + PHP. Every subdomain has this htaccess file:

```
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie

IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . ../assets/file.php [NC]
```

What's inside of file.php doesn't matter now, since I get `Error 500 - Internal Server Error` and it never points to the file.
I know that this line `RewriteRule . ../assets/file.php [NC]` is lame and will not work, but how else can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: Why don't you use HTTP2 instead of HTTP1? https://www.advancedwebranking.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http2/
**Benefits of HTTP/2** "Less dependency on hacks: Thanks to the multiplexing feature, high time consuming methods to reducing the number of requests from the server – like domain sharding"

Comment: Well, I have never heard about HTTP2 before :-) But there is a "Step 1: Make sure your website is using HTTPS" and my website is not HTTPS compatible.

Comment: browsers are actively marking insecure website though, I recommend moving to HTTPS and the sweet HTTP2 rather sooner than later.
https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/01/firefox-chrome-start-calling-http-connections-insecure/
"Firefox 51, released today, and Chrome 56, currently due for release next week, have started describing some HTTP connections as insecure as they continue the industry-wide push to promote the use of encrypted HTTPS." and that was in January

Comment: I will think about it, thanks for useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Alias (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html).

`Alias /assets /path/to/real/assets/`

This requires you to have shared assets loaded from http://static1.website.com/assets/file.js etc.

Of course you could use same `DocumentRoot` for every static[n].website.com virtual host which I would prefer if virtual hosts are identical.

Comment: It gaves me error 500, probably I don't have alias module loaded and can't enable it because of shared hosting.

Comment: You probably don't have access to apachectl, but if you do, you could confirm this with `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`.

Try this: `AliasMatch ^/static/(.*)$  /path/to/static/$1`

If this fails, please let me know which is the DocumentRoot for static1 and static2?